# How to make not null primitive fields in Spring Jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I tried to make primitive boolean type not null with @NotNull and @Column(nullable=false) annotations. But when I do post request and not send the value or send null value it assigns false to this field. But I would like it throws exception. Could anyone helps me?

```
@Column(name = "instant_del_option", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private boolean instantDelOption;
```

Comment: Primitives are never `null`.

Comment: Maybe declare it as `Boolean` instead of `boolean`?

Comment: @ernest_k ... yes, but it makes little sense.

Comment: @StephenC Mind explaining what you mean? A boolean value can be *acceptably* undefined in **some** cases.

Comment: @ernest_k - If you declare the field as `Boolean` and then add an annotation to constrain it to be `NonNull` ... as the OP is doing ... what have you actually achieved?   In this context, your suggestion makes little sense.

Comment: @StephenC I see what you're saying. But how does the value being defaulted to `false` help? (considering that the default value should change according to business logic, rather than language limitations)

Comment: Hmmm ... perhaps if the OP posted a more complete example, we could understand what he really means.  But I suspect he is trying use JPA / model constraints to validate post requests.

Comment: When i do post request from Postman and not send value for instantDelOption, I would like it would throw an exception, but it assigns false

Comment: @ZulfuqarAliyev - The way that >>I<< would do that would be to do the validation in the request method using the `@RequestParam` annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primitive type boolean can not hold a null value. If you don't assign any value, it will default to 0 which maps to false. If you want it to hold null then you have to change the datatype to Boolean. An object can hold null value.

```
@Column(name = "instant_del_option", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private Boolean instantDelOption;
```

Comment: When i do post request from Postman and not send value for instantDelOption, I would like it would throw an exception, but it assigns false